# Возникает странная ошибка при удалении элементов из вектора

Tags: c++, qt, fstream

Пишу лабораторную работу по C++. Суть написать программу на вход которой подается два файла, один с файлом с текстом другой пустой, и во второй пустой файл должны вывестись в столбик слова и рядом с ними числа показывающие сколько эти слова встречались с текстом (должны вывестись все слова которые использовались более 1 раза). Суть проста, и в принципе у меня все получилось но только почему то в одном месте при удалении элементов из вектора программа завершается с ошибкой.(причем в другом месте я удаляю элементы точно также только из другого вектора, и никакой ошибки нет)
Вот место ошибки:

```
for (int j = 0; j < wordsCount; j++) {
    if (WordNumber[j] == 1) {
    WordNumber.erase(WordNumber.begin()+j);
    }
}
```

Вот код:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <vector>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}



void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
QString firstFileName = ui->lineEdit->text();
QString secondFileName = ui->lineEdit2->text();

qDebug()<<firstFileName;
qDebug()<<secondFileName;
string thePath = "C:/Users/leoni/Desktop/Science/c++/Qtprojects/Qt projects/build-calcFrequency_lab-Desktop_Qt_6_2_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug/debug/" + firstFileName.toStdString();
string thePath2 = "C:/Users/leoni/Desktop/Science/c++/Qtprojects/Qt projects/build-calcFrequency_lab-Desktop_Qt_6_2_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug/debug/" + secondFileName.toStdString();

ifstream fin(thePath);
ofstream fout(thePath2, ios_base::trunc);
string g,t;
int wordsCount = 0;


while (fin>>t) {
    wordsCount++;
}
//string words[wordsCount];
vector <string> words(wordsCount);
fin.close();
for (int i = 0; i < wordsCount; i++) {
    words[i] = "";
}

fin.open(thePath);
int cnt = -1;
while (fin>>g) {
cnt++;
words[cnt] = g;
}

qDebug()<<wordsCount;
fin.close();
fout.close();



for (int i = 0; i < wordsCount; i++) {
    if (words[i] == "," || words[i] == "." || words[i]==":"){
        words.erase(words.begin()+i);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < wordsCount; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < words[i].length(); j++) {
        if (words[i][j] == ','||words[i][j] == '.'||words[i][j] == ':'||words[i][j] == ':'||words[i][j] == '!'||words[i][j] == '?') {
            words[i].erase(words[i].begin()+j);
        }
    }
}


//counting part:
vector <int> WordNumber (wordsCount);

for(int i = 0; i <wordsCount; i++) {
    WordNumber[i] = 0;
}

for (int i = 0; i < wordsCount; i++) {
    string theWord = "";
    for (int j = i; j < wordsCount; j++) {
        theWord = words[i];
        if (theWord == words[j]) {
            WordNumber[i]++;
        }
    }
}

for (int j = 0; j < wordsCount; j++) {//Вот место ошибки
    if (WordNumber[j] == 1) {
    WordNumber.erase(WordNumber.begin()+j);
    }
}


fout.open(thePath2,ios_base::app);
for (int i = 0; i < cnt+1; i++) {
   fout <<words[i]<<" - "<<WordNumber[i]<<endl;
}

 fout.close();

}
```

Когда я удаляю это место то все прекрасно работает, просто выводит в файл все слова вместе с теме которые были использованы один раз. Объясните пожалуйста в чем ошибка, ведь до этого места я удалял элементы из вектора точно также и все работало. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В соседнем ответе Harry объяснил, в чем проблема. А вот решение:

```
for (auto it = WordNumber.begin(); it != WordNumber.end();)
{
    if (*it == 1)
        it = WordNumber.erase(it);
    else
        ++it;
}
```

Такая запись работает для любых контейнеров, а не только для тех, на которых работают `[...]`. Например на `std::list`.

Другой вариант, т. н. erase-remove idiom:

```
WordNumber.erase(std::remove(WordNumber.begin(), WordNumber.end(), 1), WordNumber.end());
```

Также есть `std::remove_if`, которая вместо конкретного значения принимает функцию, проверяющую, нужно ли удалять элемент.

Другой вариант из C++20:

```
std::erase(WordNumber, 1);
```

Также есть `std::erase_if`, принимающий функцию.

Comment: Понял, но в код который я приложил я к сожалению не дописал одну строку в цикл по удалению, он должен выглядеть так: 
`for (int j = 0; j < wordsCount; j++) {
    if (WordNumber[j] == 1) {
    WordNumber.erase(WordNumber.begin()+j);
    words.erase(words.begin()+j);
    }
}`
Вот, мне просто надо что бы удалялось и в words и там одновременно. так как индекс слова в массиве words соответствует индексу элемента с числом таких слов. Как я могу внедрить эту строку в код который вы написали? Заранее спасибо

Comment: @leocoolguy Может использовать один вектор (структур или еще чего-то) вместо двух? Если нет, тогда `std::erase` и `std::remove` не подходят, и вам нужно переделать самый первый пример, добавив еще один итератор рядом с `it` для второго вектора.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int j = 0; j < wordsCount; j++) {
    if (WordNumber[j] == 1) {
    WordNumber.erase(WordNumber.begin()+j);
    }
}
```

Когда вы удаляете элементы, что происходит с длиной вектора? Она уменьшается. И в результате `wordsCount` перестает соответствовать длине вектора, и вы выходите за границу...

Кстати, представим, что вы удалили, ну, второй элемент. При `j==2`. Теперь на место второго стал третий... но вы его уже не проверяете - переходя к новому значению `j==3` и проверяете четвертый, ствший после удаления третьим. А третий остается пропущен.